# include static library in a static library in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, linker, static-libraries

I include the header for a static library, "libChild.a" into a second static library, "libParent.a", and then link both the child the parent into my main application, but get "undefined reference" for symbols in parent that are defined in child.  I'm using netbeans 7.0 to create both static libraries, and then copy the .a files to /usr/lib and copy the header files to /usr/include.  I use netbeans project properties to add both libraries to the main project.

Interestingly, the child library is used by itself directly in the main project code, and those references compile just fine.  It is only the uses of the child that are within the parent static lib that result in undefined reference errors.

One solution would be to merge the static libraries, using the "ar" tool..  Unfortunately, that's impractical as there are multiple versions of each, and would have to separately make a merge for each combination, and then re-merge each time a change was made in one version of either..

So, why does the netbeans build do correct linking for references to child symbols within the main code, but not in the static parent library code?  How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into the same problem, which is based on a misunderstanding.

In fact static libs do not link against each other, instead they are all linked together by their parent application.

The solution is simple, just add all required libraries to the linker config of the main application. Parent/child relationship between libs does not matter.

(In netbeans: properties/linker/libraries/addLibraryFile)